# "Remove" a testing condition once it evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm doing something with the members of an `Array`.

I need to test if the member meets some certain condition.

- Whether or not the condition is met, some code is executed on the member
- If the condition is met, some other code should be executed on the member as well.

Given that

- The condition would be met once and only once throughout the whole array.

I've already tried using a bare if statement. Like this:

```
myArray.forEach((i) => {
  if (myCondition) {
    // Do something else.
  }
  // Do something.
});
```

However, this is not ideal since I don't need to test this condition on other members of the array once it is met.

So how should I

- avoid unnecessary condition tests
- without introducing another iteration
- in an elegant way?

Thank you for your patience.

Edit: here is a more precise example.

```
Object.entries(modes).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);

    if (!currentTheme.endsWith(key)) {
      // Do something else.
      }
    element.parentElement!.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
    const clonedElement = element.parentElement!.lastElementChild;
    clonedElement!.classList.remove(currentTheme);
    // Do something. （This code is not finished.)
  });
```

Edit: another similar scenario:

Except that only on the item that meets the condition, a block of code would be executed, all other requirements are the same.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info about the data and the condition?

Comment: Not possible without adding another condition, which would be not useful at all.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you. However, I'm still not sure on this.

Comment: `.forEach()` to run on all items. Then use `.find()` to run specific code on the first item that satisfies your criteria.

Comment: @fakeinc The only elegant way i can think of is by routing all the conditional to an other function so it won't bloat your current loop. There is not much else you can do

Comment: You can't reconstruct the callback function, nor you can't can't change the function in the middle of the iteration. What else could you do? There's no way to detect a condition without checking a condition somehow. Adding a ternary operator won't remove the condition checking. You can pass that check with a flag (set in the outer scope), but that would not be helpful, and would probably be even slower that cheking something in in the scope.

Comment: @Keyboardninja , I think Dan 's solution is better. Thank you anyway. Edit: Oops I just messed up something. Sorry for this, let me edit the question again.

Comment: @Dan Sorry. I messed up something. Let me edit the question. I'm really sorry for this.

Comment: @Dan Edited the question to add another use case.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid conditions, they're incredible fast. If you don't want to execute all the code when the condition is passed, you can continue the iteration by adding `return` at the end of the `if` block.

Comment: What will this logic actually do once it's finished? Since your code seems to mention cloning DOM nodes and such, this looks like some kind of html view you're constructing. If you're only going to add/remove classes, you might be able to use clever CSS and the name of the theme on the root element. I mean something like `body.theme-name ul.some-list-class *:last-child { ... some CSS styling ... }`, instead of manually going to update the class on several nodes.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks. I think I've found a way. Will answer soon.

Comment: @Shilly I'm making a theme library and I don't want to manually duplicate the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with a global variable (here: `TYPE`) that governs which function version is to be used.

```js
myArray=[2,6,7,8,10,4,0,12,14,32,40]; // the condition that occurs only once is (v % 2)
TYPE=0;
doStuff=function(v){return [
  // regular function version (TYPE=1)
  function(v){
    if (v%2) {TYPE=1; // from now on: use simplified function version!
      console.log('Hey, I found it and will no longer look for it!')}
    console.log('Regular work on value '+v, TYPE);
    return v*v},
  // simplified function version (TYPE=2)
  function(v){console.log('Simplified work on value '+v);
    return v*v}
  
  ][TYPE](v)};

myArray.forEach(doStuff)
```

Comment: Wow! This is really great. Thank you. I'll take this.

Answer (score 0):

By using an other function we can meet 2 of your 3 requirements (elegant & no extra iteration)

```
function doStuff(theme){
  //Do stuff with the theme
  return theme
}

Object.entries(modes).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);

    if (!currentTheme.endsWith(key)) { currentTheme = doStuff(currentTheme) }

    element.parentElement!.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
    const clonedElement = element.parentElement!.lastElementChild;
    clonedElement!.classList.remove(currentTheme);
    // Do something. （This code is not finished.)
  });
```

Comment: I'd prefer no extra condition test rather than elegant. I'm sure I've found some way. Will answer my own question once I organized it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in ability to break in forEach. To interrupt execution you would have to throw an exception of some sort. eg.

```
let arrTest = [
  {
    name: 'harry',
    age: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'sam',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'max',
    age: 32
  },
  {
    name: 'james',
    age: 51
  },
  {
    name: 'robert',
    age: 42
  },
  {
    name: 'walter',
    age: 58
  },
]

var BreakException = {};

try {
  arrTest.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el);
    if (el.name === 'sam'){
        console.log('THE CONDITION IS MET!');
        throw BreakException;
    }else{
      console.warn('no no no!');
    }  
  });
} catch (e) {
  if (e !== BreakException) throw e;
}
```

or you can use a simple for loop like this -->

```
let arrTest = [
  {
    name: 'harry',
    age: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'sam',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'max',
    age: 32
  },
  {
    name: 'james',
    age: 51
  },
  {
    name: 'robert',
    age: 42
  },
  {
    name: 'walter',
    age: 58
  },
]

for(let i = 0; i <= arrTest.length; i++){
  if(arrTest[i].name === 'sam'){
    console.log('THE CONDITION IS MET!');
    break;
  }else{
    console.warn('no no no!');
  }
}
```

or if you just want to find a specific item from an array and then do something with that you can use a simple find() function on that array like this -->

```
let arrTest = [
  {
    name: 'harry',
    age: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'sam',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'max',
    age: 32
  },
  {
    name: 'james',
    age: 51
  },
  {
    name: 'robert',
    age: 42
  },
  {
    name: 'walter',
    age: 58
  },
]

let requiredItemFromAnArray = arrTest.find(el => el.name == 'sam');

console.log('requiredItemFromAnArray --> ', requiredItemFromAnArray);
```

hope it helps ;)

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I'm asking for. Maybe my question is still confusing? Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Set the condition test to something that gets changed once the condition has reached.

This way we can meet the three requirements.

It might reduce the performance of the code, but might be helpful for some more complex condition tests.

```js
const reallyApplyTheme = (currentTheme: string, key: string, element: HTMLElement) => {
  element.parentElement!.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
  const clonedElement = element.parentElement!.lastElementChild;

  clonedElement!.classList.remove('themed_active_true');
  clonedElement!.classList.add('themed_active_false');

  clonedElement!.classList.remove(currentTheme);
  clonedElement!.classList.add(`themed_theme_${key}`);
};

let applyTheme = (currentTheme: string, key: string, element: HTMLElement) => {

  if (currentTheme.endsWith(key)) {
    applyTheme = (currentTheme: string, key: string, element: HTMLElement) => {
      reallyApplyTheme(currentTheme, key, element);
    };
    return;
  }

  reallyApplyTheme(currentTheme, key, element);
};

export const duplicate = function(element: HTMLElement, modes: object) {

  const currentTheme = Array.from(element.classList).find(x => x.startsWith('themed_theme_'))!;
  console.log(currentTheme);

  Object.entries(modes).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
    applyTheme(currentTheme, key, element);
  });
};
```